# How to impute missing values at the beginning of a time series using GARCH model?

Tags: time-series, missing-data, garch, data-imputation

I want to use a GARCH(1,1) model to impute the missing data at the beginning of a time series, but GARCH model is normally used for predicting future data, is there a way to modify GARCH(1,1) so that it also works for imputing historical data?